# Extract year, month, day from a string with forward slashes

Tags: python

Given a string like
`s3://bucket/year=2023/month=02/day=22/test.csv`,
I would like to return the `year`, `month`, `day` as separate variables.

Is there some regex that can search for this? Assuming the pattern is always the same. I tried with `datetime` module, but I think the forward slashes are interfering with it.

Comment: What have you tried? Show your code [mre], incl. full traceback you get, if any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple String manipulation in Python like below, no need for a complicated regex pattern:

```
s = "s3://bucket/year=2023/month=02/day=22/test.csv"

# extract the year
year = s.split("year=")[1].split("/")[0]

# extract the month
month = s.split("month=")[1].split("/")[0]

# extract the day
day = s.split("day=")[1].split("/")[0]


print("Year:", year)
print("Month:", month)
print("Day:", day)

# Year: 2023
# Month: 02
# Day: 22
```